# Mongodb issues on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to install Mongodb on my AWS EC2 instance to work with a Node.js server I wrote.

Following [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) guide I was able to "install" monogdb

However I set to aliases to the paths of mongod and mongo since the paths were dropped when I logged out

```
alias mongod='/home/ec2-user/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.0/bin/mongod'
alias mongo='/home/ec2-user/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.0/bin/mongo'
```

I can start the mongo server using this alias no problem.

However when I run node server.js, I get

```
/home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
AssertionError: {"name":"MongoError","ok":0,"errmsg":"ns not found"} == null
    at /home/ec2-user/project/server.js:38:13
    at /home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1217:20
    at /home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1194:16
    at /home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
    at /home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:445:20)
    at emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:207:13)
```

I've searched around a bit for this error but, couldn't find anything. The odd part is I can see the incoming connection in the screened mongod proccess. As such

```
2015-03-29T20:40:45.782+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37394 #34 (1 connection now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:45.782+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37395 #35 (2 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:45.783+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37396 #36 (3 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:45.783+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37397 #37 (4 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:45.784+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:37398 #38 (5 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:46.721+0000 I COMMAND  [conn35] CMD: drop data.page-1
2015-03-29T20:40:46.749+0000 I COMMAND  [conn36] CMD: drop data.page-2
2015-03-29T20:40:46.772+0000 I COMMAND  [conn37] CMD: drop data.page-4
2015-03-29T20:40:46.803+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] CMD: drop data.page-3
2015-03-29T20:40:46.822+0000 I COMMAND  [conn34] CMD: drop data.page-5
2015-03-29T20:40:46.829+0000 I NETWORK  [conn34] end connection 127.0.0.1:37394 (4 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:46.829+0000 I NETWORK  [conn35] end connection 127.0.0.1:37395 (3 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:46.829+0000 I NETWORK  [conn36] end connection 127.0.0.1:37396 (2 connections now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:46.829+0000 I NETWORK  [conn37] end connection 127.0.0.1:37397 (1 connection now open)
2015-03-29T20:40:46.829+0000 I NETWORK  [conn38] end connection 127.0.0.1:37398 (0 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `ns not found` means some operation was run on a nonexistent namespace (ns), like you meant to operate on `database.collection` but instead tried to operate on `database.colletcion`. Does that make sense based on where the error happens in your code? If not, could you post the offending lines from your server.js?